# Diagonal of a matrix in different basis

Tags: matrices

I want to calculate the diagonal of a matrix in different basis $V' A  V$ where $V$ is the unitary matrix and $A$ is the matrix. What is the least computational expensive way?

If I calculate $V' A V$ and throw away all elements other than diagonal, it would be inefficient. I am using Matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming real matrices, 
$$
(V'AV)_{kk}=\sum_{s,t}A_{st}V_{sk}{V_{tk}}
$$

Comment: Thanks, do you know a shortcut in matlab to avoid the loop?

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with Matlab. But there is not way to avoid adding all the terms, unless in the case of a very particular form of matrix (like diagonal, etc.)